# Python get signed int from 32 bits

Tags: python

So I am reading 16 bit modbus registers to get a signed 32 int, currently I am doing this:

```
bits = (regs[0] << 16) + regs[1]
```

where regs is the array of registers which in pythons are handle as an int array

and it works for most cases, however when the number is negative then i get an underflow

For example a negative number may read as the registers being:

```
[65535, 65385]
```

which then is returned as

```
4294967145
```

Is there an easy way to fix this? Should I just be checking if the value is greater than INT32 MAX / 2 and if it is then subtract INT32 MAX? Or is there a better way?

The problem seems to be I am expecting a unsigned 32 bit int, but it should be a signed 32bit int

Comment: Several libraries have fixed-width integers, e.g. `ctypes` and `numpy`. Frankly, any sufficiently-large program will probably benefit from numpy so you might as well use it.

Comment: @o11c if you're into Weird Expressions like that, you can use `(x ^ 0x80000000) - 0x80000000`

Comment: Thanks, I think i got it working with your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to do a series of two conversions - first from unsigned 16-bit integers to bytes, then from bytes to signed 32-bit integer.

```
>>> regs = [65535, 65385]
>>> import struct
>>> b = struct.pack('>2H', *regs)
>>> b
b'\xff\xff\xffi'
>>> struct.unpack('>l', b)[0]
-151
```